# Steam won't work on Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit "libGL error: unable to load driver:"

Tags: drivers, steam

Whenever I click the steam app it won't start and when I try from the terminal it says:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

What do I do?

Comment: What driver do you use? Xorg or Nvidia or even Amd?

Comment: Did you use Valve's official package from steam.com or did you use the package in the Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a Problem with the libs from Steam.
Here is a link which discribe the problem [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183659) .
You can try to delete the file like suggested there.

Alternativly you can try start steam without this libs with adding `STEAM_RUNTIME=0`.
You can test this if you start a terminal and start steam with this like

```
STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam
```

Regards,
  Kai